# Ruby.app for use with Ruby/Gosu crashes

Tags: ruby, macos, libgosu

I downloaded the latest version of Ruby.app, a OS X app that contains a full Ruby installation (for use with Ruby/Gosu) from [here](https://github.com/gosu/ruby-app/releases)

But, after decompression, when I launch the app, it does not open. I am on OSX 10.11.5 El Capitan, Ruby 2.3.1. Gosu 0.10.7.

Answer (score 0):

From the README.md file in the root directory:

> ## Ruby.app
>
> Universal application wrapper to deploy Ruby apps on OS X (using MRI/C
>   Ruby, not MacRuby or JRuby). So far, it has only been used to release
>   [Ruby/Gosu](https://github.com/jlnr/gosu) games. It can probably be
>   adapted to wrap applications or games written in other toolkits.
>
> The idea is that `Ruby.app` contains a full, universal Ruby
>   installation. ***All you have to do is provide a `main.rb` file inside
>   the `Ruby.app/Contents/Resources/` folder that starts your
>   game/application***.

Comment: Done that, the app won't launch.

Comment: With the "older" versions of same app, you can double-click it and the app opens, showing a big rotating ruby. You have then to replace the main.rb file with your game.